# Can I make Parallel.For consume user defined threads? C#

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow make parallel.for or parallel.foreach consume threads that only are assigned/created by a user. Is this even possible?

Comment: first question you should ask is why you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an overload which has a [`ParallelOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) parameter (such as [this one for `Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781401.aspx)), and create such an options object using a custom [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx). It's not going to be terribly easy, admittedly... but it's doable.

For more information about task schedulers, see the [MSDN section about them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx) and some [samples](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=165717).

Comment: Dear Jon, thank you so much, hope I can go through it or may be someone can guide me via snippet!!!

Comment: @Wajih: I haven't done it myself, but apparently there are examples: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples

Comment: lovely mate! I feel proud that Jon Skeet is answering! Thanks once again indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) that somehow passes the delegates to your threads.

Comment: If I only knew how to!!!! Guess I will have to dive into the Task Parallel Library!

Comment: Correct; you cannot use the library that deeply without understanding it.